# Cakephp3 elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one problem. In cakephp 3.x I created type and document. In AppController I put "$this->loadModel('VideosIndex', 'Elastic');", "VideosIndex" is my Type. I have error "Unknown repository type "Elastic". Make sure you register a type before trying to use it.". I tried many things, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, specify what exactly did you try, then it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: I created folder Document->VideoIndex.php. In VideoIndex.php I add "<?php
namespace App\Model\Document;
use Cake\ElasticSearch\Document;
class VideoIndex extends Document{}"  then I created Type->VideosIndexType.php. In VideosIndexType.php I add "<?php
namespace App\Model\Type;
use Cake\ElasticSearch\Type;
class VideosIndexType extends Type{}". I add in AppController "$this->loadModel('VideosIndex', 'Elastic');".

Comment: then in VideosTable.php I add "$video = $this->VideosIndex->find()
            ->where([
                'or' => [
                    'title' => $keyword,
                    'body' => $hashTag
                ]
            ])->toArray();
        dump($video);". But it doestn't work.